# How do I set an image as my custom lock screen image without any widgets on Android 4.4.4?

Tags: lock-screens, wallpaper

I have made an image that I'd like to use as my lockscreen "wallpaper". Except, I don't want it to be a wallpaper, I want it to be the only thing I see on the lockscreen with no unlock button or widgets on top. I don't mind if the status bar is there or not and it would be great to put a clock and the weather on there, but it's not necessary.

I've tried a lot of lock screen replacements, but haven't found one which will remove all the periphery and just let me set the image as the lock screen without any widgets or a lock icon on top. Do you know of anything?

For reference, I'd love to be able to swipe to unlock the screen.